# Design pattern for no internet message

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a e-commerce application which has several screen. When ever there is no internet, need to show specific fragment with message "no internet available". Once internet is back this fragment should disappear and previously loaded fragment should be shown.

What kind of design should be used for this kind of problem?

Comment: Constantly trying to check for a connection to the server seems like a battery drain

Comment: You have to use `BroadcastReceiver` for this.

Comment: You should respond/select the answers that make sense to you or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its a pattern, but I would use a BaseActivity and a common layout to all activities with just a fragment container in it, then:

1. Make each of your activities display their content inside the mentioned container.
2. Logic to handle internet connection/disconnection will be in BaseActivity, which in turn
3. Will take care of replacing the current content in fragment container when internet is gone, and switch it back later.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends upon how the UX/Product guy wants it handled.

The 2 most common approaches [these are not design patterns certainly] are

1) Have a BaseActivity/BaseFragment and include a layout. Whenever your network state changes you shoot a LocalBroacast from `LocalBroadcastManager` which you BaseActivity/BaseFragment listens to. And here make the included layout visible or gone depending upon the condition.

2) The second approach is that you donot proactively listen to network state changes, but use `ConnectivityManager` [Android has a nice article here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) before making a network request in an api like

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                          activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    return isConnected;
}
```

when isConnected is false, show an error in any screen using the same approach as in pt 1.